# clearInterval is not clearing the interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this question has been asked so many times... but i think i'm doing everything correctly still it's not working, clearInterval doesn't stop the interval, the function is still being called  every 1 second.

Here is my full code:

```
  const [playerState, setPlayerState] = useState({ playing: true });
  let [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

  let counter = null; 
  let count = () => {
    setDuration(++duration);
  };

  let handlePlay = () => {
    setPlayerState({ playing: true });
    counter = setInterval(count, 1000); //call count every 1 second, working fine
    console.log("playing");
    console.log(duration);
  };

  let handlePause = () => {
    setPlayerState({ playing: false });
    clearInterval(counter);   // doesn't work the function is still being called  every 1 second.
    console.log("paused");
    console.log(duration);
  };
```

On calling handePlay the duration should increase by 1 every 1 second that is working fine, after calling handlePause the duration should stop increasing but it's not!
thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time your component function gets called to render the component (which is after any series of state changes), a **new** `counter` local variable is created. The one in which you stored the timer handle no longer exists. You have to save the timer handle somewhere you'll be able to use it later (state or a ref, basically). You also need to be sure to have a cleanup callback when your component unmounts that cancels the timer.

See comments:

```
const [playerState, setPlayerState] = useState({ playing: true });
let [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

// A ref to hold the timer handle
const timerRef = useRef(0);

// Register an unmount callback
useEffect(() => {
    // The return value is the clean up callback
    return () => {
        clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    };
}, []); // <== Empty dependency array means callback is called on unmount only

let count = () => {
    setDuration(++duration);
};

let handlePlay = () => {
    setPlayerState({ playing: true });
    // *** Use the ref
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    timerRef.current = setInterval(count, 1000); //call count every 1 second, working fine
    console.log("playing");
    console.log(duration);
};

let handlePause = () => {
    setPlayerState({ playing: false });
    // *** Use the ref
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    timerRef.current = 0;
    console.log("paused");
    console.log(duration);
};
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense ,I'm new to react i really don't know how useRef works i think i should learn it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When `handlePlay` is called, it calls `setPlayerState`. This triggers a rerender, which results in a new `counter` with the value `null`. The new `handlePause` has a closure around this value. You can try assigning your counter to state/ref.